# AC not rectified to DC properly

Tags: operational-amplifier, brushless-dc-motor, thermistor

So I am trying to make a temperature controlled DC fan using IC as voltage comparator. The IC I am using is LM741. This is the layout of my circuit:
[image]

Now when I use a 9V battery as power supply, the circuit works fine. But I want to run this circuit using wall socket. So I used a step down transformer to get 12V AC and used this to rectify it:

[image]

But the circuit does not work properly. The fan is always on and is not switched off by adjusting the trimpot. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
I checked the output of the rectifier circuit using DMM, I get around 15.6V DC.

Edit: I am sorry I messed up while drawing the circuit... I did not actually connect the ground of the circuit the way I drew it.. This is how I connected the circuit:[image]

Comment: You should be getting your DC ground/0V from the negative side of the smoothing cap, not the bottom of your bridge rectifier.

Comment: Ditto what he said AND the capacitor is drawn incorrectly polarized. Show precisely how you connected your rectifier circuit to your fan circuit.

Comment: Look at this circuit: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CUDybdFZvfo/VJqQW333arI/AAAAAAAAAls/Lj2Gq3t522o/s1600/Bridge%2BRectifier.png  Build that and it should work. Place your C1 in parallel with the + and - outputs. so not between the diodes like in your drawing.

Comment: Please see edit..

Comment: "The fan is always on and is not switched off by adjusting the trimpot" - not enough information. Disconnect R1 and measure the voltages on pins 2, 3 and 6 of the 741. Are they what you expect? Is the motor now off? If not then check that Q1 is connected correctly (if the Collector and Emitter were swapped then it would turn off at 9V but not at 15V).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Your grounding is messed up.  You only show one of the transformer outputs, labeled "12 V 50 Hz AC", so the other is implied to be connected to ground.  However, the "+15V" node is then not 15 V with respect to ground.

You should consider the negative side of the full wave bridge to be ground, then NOT ground either transformer output.

This would have been more obvious if you had drawn the schematic properly.  Try to put high voltages at top, low voltages at bottom, and logical flow left to right.  Here is the circuit you really want, properly shown to be as little confusing as possible:

[image]

Your overall circuit could be better too:

[image]

Instead of a emitter follower, I'd use a low side NPN in common emitter switch configuration.  Since the 741 opamp can't get all the way to the negative supply, use a voltage divider to drive the transistor base.  At 15 V, there is plenty of voltage available.  Arrange the resistors so that the transistor doesn't come on until the opamp output is at least 5 V or so above the negative supply.

The 741 opamp is not a good choice for comparator, but can be made to work in this situation.

As WhatRoughBeast mentioned in a comment, a little hysteresis would be good too.  You want to make sure the fan is driven either fully on or fully off, not in-between due to noise when the opamp inputs are nearly equal.  A high-value resistor from the opamp output to its positive input will provide some hysteresis.  This will have the effect of "snap action".  That keeps both the fan and the transistor from being run partly on, which could cause a lot of dissipation and damage them.

Comment: You might also suggest some hysterisis.

Comment: @What: Good point.  Added.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is your Vpp swing specs on 741 is +-10Vmin for a +-15V supply rated at 1k load.  You need a swing that is <= 0.5V from V+ regardless of ripple with a 741 load of about 5% of fan current of est. 150 mA (due to hFE reduced when saturated) or ~8mA.

Given you have a single supply then swing at high current on 15V is reduced so that with NO Rbe pullup plus Vout cannot reach Vcc-0.5 so PNP CANNOT turn off.

- Adding 1 to 2 diodes is optional to improve noise margin and thermal drift of Vbe.

  - Since this is an emitter follower Fan voltage also drops from 15 to 12.
- adding caps to O.A. inputs, to reduce stray noise is desirable, even essential with long wire hookups.
- choosing Diode bridge rectifier ought to be based on load **Req*C>=8/f** for 10% ripple. with f=120 or 100Hz and R depending on fan
- \$Req=\frac{V^2_{cc}}{Watt}\ \$
- e.g. 2.8W fan @12V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbiHZa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- \$12^2/2.8= 51\Omega\$ thus \$C4>8/{100Hz*51\Omega}=1500\mu F\$  (nearest)

I drew battery for laziness but imagine diode bridge 12V transformer

A far simpler more efficient driver uses an NPN open collector with similar diode series or a comparator that drives to ground with Pullup R 10x load R. Suitable caps to reduce noise. Hysteresis not necessary , in fact some negative feedback with 1M gives a smooth speed control over a narrow range.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good reasons not to use the LM741: -

- Minimum recommended power supply rails are +/- 10 volts (a definite problem)
- Input voltage range is typically from -Vs + 2 volt to +Vs - 2 volt
- Input offset voltage is typically 1 mV (5 mV maximum)
- Input offset current is typically 20 nA (200 nA maximum)
- Input bias current is typically 80 nA (500 nA maximum)
- Input resistance is typically 2 Mohm (300 kohm minimum)
- Typical output voltage swing is -Vs + 1 volt to +Vs - 1 volt
- Guaranteed output voltage swing is -Vs + 3 volt to +Vs - 3 volt
- Supply current is typically 1.7 mA (2.8 mA maximum)
- Noise is 60 nV/sqrt(Hz) for LM348 (quad version of 741)
- GBWP is 1 MHz with a slew rate of 0.5 V/us

The LM741A is slightly better but still a dinosaur in most areas.

---

So point 1 and 2 are being contravened due to low voltage supply of only 9 volts and pot wiper going down to 0 V and up to positive supply. Because the output cannot swing down to 0V (guaranteed to swing to 0 volts plus 3 volts) your fan's top speed is severely limited (may not be a problem of course).

Regards your bridge rectifier you really need to set this up properly - at the moment with the capacitor shown as it is, it is reverse polarized.

And of course, I hear you say "but it works at 9 volts". Well that's not the way to design things - you design to the data sheet and work within the restrictions they impose.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is your Vpp swing specs on 741 is 10Vmin for a 15V supply rated at 1k load.  You need a swing that is <= 0.5V from V+ regardless of ripple with a 741 load of about 5% of fan current of est. 150 mA (due to hFE reduced when saturated) or ~8mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftcTcX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>